# Python3 Base64 decode of a var containing ==

Tags: python-3.x, base64

So Ive got a string of:
YDNhZip1cDg1YWg4cCFoKg==
that needs to be decoded using Pythons Base64 module.

Ive written the code

```
import base64

test = 'YDNhZip1cDg1YWg4cCFoKg=='
print(test)
print(base64.b64decode(test))
```

which gives the answer
b'`3af*up85ah8p!h*'
when, according to the website decoders Ive used, its really

`3af*up85ah8p!h*

Im guessing that its decoding the additional quotes.
Is there some way that I can save this variable with a delimiter, as another type of variable, or run the b64encode on a section of the string as slice doesnt seem to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b' is Python's way of delimiting data from bytes, see: [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

i.e., it is decoding it correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks. I need to use the returned value so Im hoping that this additional characters wont cause a problem or using .decode("utf-8") will take care of it. (Being fed back to a POST to a website looking for a specific value)